Issue with Voltage Transformation in LTSpice Simulation of LTC3108-01 Energy Harvesting Circuit
I am working on simulating an Energy Harvesting circuit for MEMS applications using the LTC3108-01 in LTSpice. However, I’m running into an issue with the voltage transformation in the circuit. I’m relatively new to electronics and LTSpice, and would appreciate any insights or guidance on this.
I am generating an AC input signal with 35mV amplitude at 840Hz. My understanding is that this voltage should be transformed by the transformer in the circuit. I am using a 1:100 transformer and have selected the value for C4 based on the formula in the datasheet (found here: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/31081fb.pdf).
When I test the circuit with higher input voltages (e.g., 350mV), the transformation works as expected, resulting in an transformed Voltage of 35V. However, when I reduce the input to 35mV, the output only reaches around 70mV, instead of the expected 3.5V.
Also, as far as I understand the Voltages V_AUX has to reach 2.5 V (defined by LTC3108-1) for V_out to receive any Power. But the small input voltage leads to a saturation curve, that only reached around 350mV.
What are the potential reasons for why the voltage isn’t transforming correctly at lower input levels?


Why do you expect 3.5 volts at the output?

I expect 3.5V at the output because the transformer is designed with a 1:100 ratio, so 35mV * 100 should give 3.5V. I got the formula for the Turns Ratios from Here: https://www.analog.com/en/resources/technical-articles/ltspice-basic-steps-for-simulating-transformers.html

Vout is defined by VS1 and VS2

I trust you are referring to stable Vpp levels as in the sheet.


Find a way to measure input current as Rin is very nonlinear and complex.
Validate every spec and find out which is not matching.  The attenuation is always about impedance ratios.  Try changing f to see if there is a resonant frequency not tuned properly by changing C or f.

